# 'Tokenizing' sections of text while processing text file

Tags: c#, markup, text-processing

I'm working on a hobby project to port an existing markup library into a C# / .NET Class Library. If you're familiar with Markdown, it's a similar concept.

One early question I have is that there is a syntax for marking a section of text to stop it from being processed by any of the other syntax rules, and I'd like some advice on this.

One method that occurs to me is to search for these sections first, remove and replace them with some sort of meaningful token, run the rest of the processing rules, and then as the last step, replace the tokens with the text they represent.

Is that what makes the most sense to others? Also, how would you generate the tokens such that you don't face the possibility that you might accidentally create a token that matches existing text?

Any help / advice appreciated!

pt

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a proper parser generator to create your tokenizer?

You could probably knock something together with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) in a few hours.

Comment: I'm actually interested in building the parser myself -- I did something similar in a PHP project some years ago. Currently, I'm just interested in the conceptual approach to breaking this down into concrete tasks.